# Is CiviCRM right for a non-profit medical group?

Tags: activities, evaluating-civicrm

Would CiviCRM be appropriate for a 501(c)(3) medical group practice's philanthropic endeavors?

Comment: It would certainly help me if you can explain what a 501(c)(3) etc. is? It means nothing to me here in The Netherlands :-)

Comment: If you explain a little bit about what you are trying to accomplish with the software, folks here are happy to help you.

Comment: @ErikH and others - in the US, non-profit organizations are commonly referred to by status under sections of the Internal Revenue Code. So, a 501(c)3 organization is tax-exempt and contributions to it are exempt from US Federal income tax. "c3"s typically have an educational or philanthropic purpose. 501(c)4 organizations are "membership" organizations and can engage in some political and advocacy activity, but contributions to it are not tax exempt. See https://www.irs.gov/Charities-&-Non-Profits/Charitable-Organizations/Exemption-Requirements-Section-501(c)(3)-Organizations

Comment: @Patricia Harger, the StackExchange format works best to answer specific questions, and is not good for broad, open-ended questions that can have multiple different answers. Please be more specific about your needs.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing what your organization is trying to do, it is difficult to provide meaningful feedback. You should take a look at CiviCRM's [features](https://civicrm.org/features) and see if it fits your need. At the bottom of the [site](https://civicrm.org/) you'll find some useful links, including:

Browse case studies, 
Contact an ambassador,
Introductory webinars,
Watch videos,
Try a demo,
Read documentation,
Ask a question,
Find an expert

Answer (score 0):

If you are needing to track/administer contacts, organizations, contact relationships and outgoing grants, then yes, CiviCRM would suit your organization quite well.

See this link for the grant component: [What is CiviGrant?](http://book.civicrm.org/user/grants/what-is-civigrant/)